# If the derivative of a function is continuous at all points, can we say that the function is also differentiable at all points??

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

If the derivative of a function is continuous at all points, can we say that the function is also differentiable at all points?

Comment: Can yo u talk about continuity of  a function that is not even known to exist?

Answer (score 2):

If the derivative of $f$ is continuous at all points then, in particular, the derivative of $f$ *exists* at all points. And that is enough to assert that $f$ is differentiable at all points.

Comment: is-vice versa also true?

Comment: No. A function $f$ may be differentiable at all points and, even so, $f'$ might not be continuous everywhere. Take, for instance,$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$